# Line under featured tab missing in Chrome

Tags: bug

It seems to be some minor CSS issue. When not hovering over the featured tab, it hides part of title grey line. And it's OK when hovering over it.

[image: When not hovering]

[image: When hovering]

I'm using the Windows 10 OS, with Chrome 66.0.3359.117.

I tried to remove `vertical-align: middle` of `#tabs .bounty-indicator-tab and .tabs .bounty-indicator-tab` in `primary.css`, and it seems to work fine. The blue box moved up a little, and the line is perfectly shown.

Comment: Windows 7 - Chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 ..... There is no issue.

Comment: No repro - you sure you aren't running any userscripts that could manipulate the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

Found out it is caused by Chrome's setting of minimum font size. When using 'Chinese Simplified' as Chrome's display language, the default minimum font size is 12px, not 10px as English. So the bounty count number is bigger than it is designed, and the box of featured overlapped some of the grey line.